# How to save Customer Extension attribute in Magento 2/2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

**Issue:**
I am stuck at the last step of saving Customer's extension attribute using the plugin method.

***My code***

> /etc/extension_attribute.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
        <attribute code="test" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

> /etc/di.xml

```
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="get_tto_attributes" type="Tto\Custom\Plugin\CustomerGet"/> 
        <plugin name="save_tto_attributes" type="Tto\Custom\Plugin\CustomerSave"/> 
    </type>  

    <!-- plugin to retirve customer extension attribute -->
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer">
        <plugin name="get_extension_attributes" type="Tto\Custom\Plugin\CustomerAttributesLoad"/>
    </type>
```

> Tto\Custom\Plugin\CustomerSave

```
<?php
/**
 * Save customer plugin
 * we are adding/saving our custom extension attributes
 */
namespace Tto\Custom\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class CustomerSave
{   /**
    * initiate
    */
    public function __construct( 
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        CustomerRepository $customerRepo,
        CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    )
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->customerRepo = $customerRepo;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    }

    /**
     *  after save interceptor
     */
    public function afterSave(
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $subject,
        $customer
    ) {
        $this->logger->debug('afterSave Started', array('customer OBJ' => $customer, 'subject OBJ' => $subject ));

        $result = $this->saveTtoAttribute($customer);

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     *  function to save our attributes
     */
    private function saveTtoAttribute( $customer )
    {
        $this->logger->debug('saveTtoAttribute Started', array('object' => $customer ));

        //get customer id and initiate \Magento\Customer\Model\customer Object using customer factory
           // TO DO
         /** get current extension attributes from entity **/
        $extensionAttributes = $customer->getExtensionAttributes();
        $this->logger->debug('extensionAttributes', array('object' =>  $extensionAttributes ));
        try{

            $testData = $extensionAttributes->getTest();
            $this->logger->debug( 'test', array( 'object' =>  $testData ));
            $this->customerFactory->save($testData);

        }catch( CouldNotSaveException $e  ){

            $this->logger->debug('could not save');

        }

        //$ourCustomData = $extensionAttributes->getOurCustomData();
       // $this->logger->debug('ourcustomData', array('object' =>  $ourCustomData ));
        //$this->customDataRepository->save($ourCustomData);


        return $customer;
    }

}
```

Now I am stuck with correct use of `$this->customerFactory->save($testData);` in `saveTtoAttribute()` function.

According to Magento2 DevDocs http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html
use of `$this->customDataRepository->save($ourCustomData);` in `afterSave()` function

**I can't figure out which Repository(in place of customDataRepository) I should use to save the extension attribute data?**

Currently, I cant save the data.